# Activeadmin and Paperclip : ArgumentError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, activeadmin

I use Activeadmin, paperclip and Rails 4.
When i want to create a new article with multi images, I have this Error :

```
ArgumentError in Admin::Articles#new
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

When I try with just one image I have the same error.

ActiveAdmin : article.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register Article do

  controller do
    def permitted_params
      params.permit article: [:title, :images_attributes => [:picture, :id, :_destroy]]
    end
  end

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Project Details" do
      f.input :title
      f.has_many :images do |p|
        p.inputs do
          p.input :_destroy, :as => :boolean, :label => "Destroy?" unless p.object.new_record?
          p.input :picture, :as => :file, :hint => p.object.new_record? ? "" : f.template.image_tag(p.object.picture.url(:thumb))
        end
      end
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

Models : article.rb

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

Models : image.rb

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
  has_attached_file :picture, :styles => { :large => "960x640>", :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "150x150>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
end
```

Migration :

```
class CreateImages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :images do |t|
      t.belongs_to :article
      t.attachment :picture
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Full trace of my error :

```
paperclip (4.1.1) lib/paperclip/has_attached_file.rb:83:in `block in add_required_validations'
formtastic (2.3.0.rc2) lib/formtastic/inputs/base/validations.rb:39:in `call'
formtastic (2.3.0.rc2) lib/formtastic/inputs/base/validations.rb:39:in `validator_relevant?'
formtastic (2.3.0.rc2) lib/formtastic/inputs/base/validations.rb:27:in `block in validations'
formtastic (2.3.0.rc2) lib/formtastic/inputs/base/validations.rb:26:in `select'
formtastic (2.3.0.rc2) lib/formtastic/inputs/base/validations.rb:26:in `validations'
formtastic (2.3.0.rc2) lib/formtastic/inputs/base/validations.rb:129:in `validations?'
formtastic (2.3.0.rc2) lib/formtastic/inputs/base/validations.rb:136:in `required?'
formtastic (2.3.0.rc2) lib/formtastic/inputs/base/labelling.rb:25:in `requirement_text_or_proc'
formtastic (2.3.0.rc2) lib/formtastic/inputs/base/labelling.rb:29:in `requirement_text'
formtastic (2.3.0.rc2) lib/formtastic/inputs/base/labelling.rb:20:in `label_text'
formtastic (2.3.0.rc2) lib/formtastic/inputs/base/labelling.rb:9:in `label_html'
formtastic (2.3.0.rc2) lib/formtastic/inputs/file_input.rb:36:in `block in to_html'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `block in capture'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:200:in `with_output_buffer'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `capture'
formtastic (2.3.0.rc2) lib/formtastic/inputs/base/wrapping.rb:11:in `input_wrapping'
formtastic (2.3.0.rc2) lib/formtastic/inputs/file_input.rb:35:in `to_html'
formtastic (2.3.0.rc2) lib/formtastic/helpers/input_helper.rb:241:in `input'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:26:in `block in input'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:151:in `with_new_form_buffer'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:26:in `input'
app/admin/article.rb:16:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:143:in `block in field_set_and_list_wrapping'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `block in capture'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:200:in `with_output_buffer'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `capture'
formtastic (2.3.0.rc2) lib/formtastic/helpers/fieldset_wrapper.rb:32:in `field_set_and_list_wrapping'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:142:in `field_set_and_list_wrapping'
formtastic (2.3.0.rc2) lib/formtastic/helpers/inputs_helper.rb:292:in `inputs'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:20:in `block in inputs'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:151:in `with_new_form_buffer'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:20:in `inputs'
app/admin/article.rb:14:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:61:in `call'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:61:in `block in has_many'
formtastic (2.3.0.rc2) lib/formtastic/helpers/inputs_helper.rb:375:in `call'
formtastic (2.3.0.rc2) lib/formtastic/helpers/inputs_helper.rb:375:in `block (2 levels) in inputs_for_nested_attributes'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:143:in `block in field_set_and_list_wrapping'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `block in capture'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:200:in `with_output_buffer'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `capture'
formtastic (2.3.0.rc2) lib/formtastic/helpers/fieldset_wrapper.rb:32:in `field_set_and_list_wrapping'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:142:in `field_set_and_list_wrapping'
formtastic (2.3.0.rc2) lib/formtastic/helpers/inputs_helper.rb:292:in `inputs'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:20:in `block in inputs'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:151:in `with_new_form_buffer'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:20:in `inputs'
formtastic (2.3.0.rc2) lib/formtastic/helpers/inputs_helper.rb:373:in `block in inputs_for_nested_attributes'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `block in capture'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:200:in `with_output_buffer'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `capture'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1864:in `block in fields_for_nested_model'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `block in capture'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:200:in `with_output_buffer'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `capture'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:699:in `fields_for'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1863:in `fields_for_nested_model'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1849:in `block in fields_for_with_nested_attributes'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1847:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1847:in `fields_for_with_nested_attributes'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1521:in `fields_for'
formtastic (2.3.0.rc2) lib/formtastic/helpers/inputs_helper.rb:391:in `inputs_for_nested_attributes'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:176:in `block in js_for_has_many'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:151:in `with_new_form_buffer'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:176:in `js_for_has_many'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:99:in `block in has_many'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:160:in `block in without_wrapper'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:151:in `with_new_form_buffer'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:160:in `without_wrapper'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:90:in `has_many'
app/admin/article.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:143:in `block in field_set_and_list_wrapping'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `block in capture'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:200:in `with_output_buffer'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `capture'
formtastic (2.3.0.rc2) lib/formtastic/helpers/fieldset_wrapper.rb:32:in `field_set_and_list_wrapping'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:142:in `field_set_and_list_wrapping'
formtastic (2.3.0.rc2) lib/formtastic/helpers/inputs_helper.rb:292:in `inputs'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:20:in `block in inputs'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:151:in `with_new_form_buffer'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:20:in `inputs'
app/admin/article.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/lib/active_admin/views/pages/form.rb:23:in `instance_exec'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/lib/active_admin/views/pages/form.rb:23:in `block in main_content'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `block in capture'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:200:in `with_output_buffer'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `capture'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:435:in `form_for'
formtastic (2.3.0.rc2) lib/formtastic/helpers/form_helper.rb:167:in `block in semantic_form_for'
formtastic (2.3.0.rc2) lib/formtastic/helpers/form_helper.rb:190:in `with_custom_field_error_proc'
formtastic (2.3.0.rc2) lib/formtastic/helpers/form_helper.rb:166:in `semantic_form_for'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/lib/active_admin/view_helpers/form_helper.rb:9:in `active_admin_form_for'
arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element.rb:175:in `method_missing'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/lib/active_admin/views/pages/form.rb:22:in `main_content'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:83:in `block (2 levels) in build_main_content_wrapper'
arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:31:in `block in build_tag'
arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:14:in `div'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:82:in `block in build_main_content_wrapper'
arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:31:in `block in build_tag'
arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:14:in `div'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:81:in `build_main_content_wrapper'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:65:in `block in build_page_content'
arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:31:in `block in build_tag'
arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:14:in `div'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:64:in `build_page_content'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in build_page'
arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:31:in `block in build_tag'
arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:14:in `div'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:44:in `block in build_page'
arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:49:in `with_current_arbre_element'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:43:in `build_page'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:10:in `build'
arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:30:in `block in build_tag'
arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:92:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:26:in `build_tag'
arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:39:in `insert_tag'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/app/views/active_admin/resource/new.html.arb:1:in `block in __home_bibou__rvm_gems_ruby_______p____bundler_gems_active_admin___de_f__ae_d_app_views_active_admin_resource_new_html_arb__2699006568721876069_69819426589980'
arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:45:in `instance_eval'
arbre (1.0.1) lib/arbre/context.rb:45:in `initialize'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/app/views/active_admin/resource/new.html.arb:1:in `new'
/home/bibou/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bundler/gems/active_admin-66de2f86ae1d/app/views/active_admin/resource/new.html.arb:1:in `__home_bibou__rvm_gems_ruby_______p____bundler_gems_active_admin___de_f__ae_d_app_views_active_admin_resource_new_html_arb__2699006568721876069_69819426589980'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:48:in `block in render_template'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:56:in `render_with_layout'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `render_template'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:127:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:219:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:120:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:33:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:26:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:97:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
/home/bibou/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:296:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:233:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:161:in `to_html'
responders (1.0.0) lib/responders/flash_responder.rb:104:in `to_html'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:154:in `respond'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:147:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:330:in `respond_with'
inherited_resources (1.4.1) lib/inherited_resources/actions.rb:19:in `new'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:433:in `_run__2406119207582674973__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:680:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__1775309793310121907__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/home/bibou/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/bibou/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/bibou/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Thank you for your help

Edit :

I use this gem for my project :

```
gem 'devise'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
gem 'annotate'
gem 'ckeditor'
gem "paperclip", "~> 4.1"
```

My OS is a Ubuntu and I use ImageMagick-6.8.8-7.

When I run `which convert`
I have : `/usr/local/bin/convert`

development.rb

```
PaperclipActiveadmin::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # configure paperclip
  Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"

end
```

Solution :

add `require: false` to my input :

```
p.input :picture, :as => :file, :hint => p.object.new_record? ? "" : f.template.image_tag(p.object.picture.url(:thumb)), required: false
```

And in my image.rb add a `validates_attachment_content_type` :

```
validates_attachment_content_type :picture, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png"]
```

Thank You Philip Hallstrom for your help and your solution

Comment: First, please use uniform spaces for your indentation. You are using both 4 and 2 spaces, sometimes in the same file. The Ruby community suggests using 2 spaces. Are you sure you have all of the gems installed (paperclip requires ImageMagick, an external program). Also, what OS are you on? I think there should be more of a trace.

Comment: I have edited my post with the 2 spaces suggests. My OS is a Ubuntu and my version of ImageMagick is v6.8.8-7.

Comment: No solution, but I too am now experiencing this error.

Comment: Also see https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/issues/999

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/issues/999 the temporary solution is to add `require: false` to your input.  Like so:

```
f.input :image, required: false
```

Just tried it and it works for me.

Comment: It's now fixed in 2.3.0.rc3, I just had to update to the latest version.